# Laravel file storage outside of application directory on Ubuntu permissions error

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-22.04

I'm running a laravel project on apache/ubuntu which is stored in `/var/www/projects/my-project`. I have a storage folder that I'm trying to use found at `/home/my-user-name/my-storage`. When I go into `php artisan tinker` and use `Storage::disk('ubuntu')->files('/my/sub/directory')`, I get the array of file names as expected. However, when I go to my application in the browser and click the button that routes to the controller method containing the exact same `Storage::files()` method, I get the error of:

`Unable to create a directory at /home/my-user-name/my-storage.`

My "ubuntu" disk is as such:

```
        'ubuntu'=> [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => '/home/my-user/my-storage'
        ],
```

The `www-data` user has 777 permissions on both my project directory at `/var/www/projects/my-project` and the `/home/user/my-storage` directory.

My php.ini file has 2G set as the `post_max_size` as well as the `upload_max_filesize`. I only have one php version installed and phpinfo() confirms that I'm loading the correct ini file.

What's strange is that I'm getting an "unable to CREATE a directory" error when I'm simply trying to READ the files in the directory.

I should also note that `open_basedir` is commented out in my php.ini as well. So no restrictions there. If anyone can help me put this two-day nightmare to bed, I'd be eternally in your debt.

Comment: A home directory is not the place to store files. Put it somewhere else.

Comment: the question still stands with any directory that is not the specific project directory in the www folder. so replace "home" with any other directory that's not www that you like and the issue is the same

Comment: You are saying you have 777 permissions on /home/user/my-storage. But you are not trying to save there instead saving on /home/my-user-name/my-storage.

Comment: that's a typo on my part. the directories are congruent

Comment: ‘ ln -ls /home/my-user-name/my-storage storage ‘ in laravel directory and just use standard srotage path. Permissions on folder must be read for webserver user and r+w for php user